# Ideal method for handling multiple VDDs in a system

Tags: power-supply

I am trying to "glue" a bunch of existing components together and it's turning into a power supply nightmare.  I am trying to determine the best way to generate relative voltages for all of the different components around a common ground.

In the previous version of this hardware, a transformer existed with a bunch of taps were used with isolated supplies.  I am adding a MCU that will have an optoisolator to the USB so that it is not "yanked" anywhere.   I have a good ground that exists, but that's about my only saving grace.  The overview of the system follows.

[image: messy power]

I have an ADC input that will have the "common gnd" about 1/2 way up the range.  The ADC that was previously used was the standard SAR with 5V rails and the ADC had 3.3v tolerant inputs.  The MCU runs at 3.3V and just doles out SPI commands.  +-11V exist for an amplifier that I have not included.

The point, I have a real power supply mess, and I feel that I should redesign the system instead of trying to glue it together, but I need a compelling argument outside of complexity.

Does anyone have any experience dealing with an issue where multiple supplies are required?

Comment: Is the 3.3V regulator really between V+ to the +11V regulator and the -2.5V regulator output?

Comment: Due to how the components are setup, the -2.5 is the "GND" for the MCU.  The 3.3V comes from the unregulated output of a 24V module with the -2.5V being a relative GND.

Comment: I'm sorry.  Maybe there's a good reason for connecting it that way, but it just looks nuts.

Comment: @JRE yeah, it's ludicrous.  There's 100s of components in the actual design, so my "power diagram" doesn't really describe the "why".  If I was happy with it, I wouldn't have asked for wisdom of others.

Comment: Can't you offset and buffer the ADC input to get rid of the negative 2.5V?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When designing boards with lots of power levels try to do this:

- Figure out your load requirements, expect the worst
- Look for possibilities to make an high amp intermediate rail from your "dirty" raw input". This can be filtered and placed where cooling is adequate
- Sensitive loads might benefit from using an LDO from the intermediate rail
- Draw a logical diagram (like you did) of how you think the system should look like
- Make a spreadsheet with all voltages and regulators, add currents and losses to each.
- Last but not least: Power sequencing. Figure out if, for instance the MCU 3.3 V must be stable before the ADC supply, or something else is up and running.

I'm not sure why you have that strange -2.5V ground to the MCU and ADC. You should be able to offset the input voltage to the ADC?

I have drawn something quick and dirty based on your drawing:

[image]

This design uses a TI TPS5140 for the MCU, ADC and amplifier. The 5 V is fed to two TI TPS63700 for the negative supplies. Note that the amplifier gets 12 V from the regulators fixed internal LDO, not sure if it works for you.

A better alternative to the TPS5140 might be something like Linear LTC3544 which has four adjustable outputs with internal switches, but with lesser power output.

Answer (score 1):

If those are the voltages you require, then you need a regulator for each one. You have options though, if your current requirements are not very high, you can use an IC with multiple regulators which will save space, which would be an option if your only running an amplifier and an ADC. They shouldn't require much current.

A few things that you might want to consider. It may be wise to use a DC to DC for the 11V line and then use regulators after that. 24V to 11V is a big drop. I'm a big fan of the 780X drop in replacement DC to DC converters, you can even generate negative voltages from a positive rail, then you can do away with the negative rail. I've also seen DC to DC IC's on digikey with 3 outputs.

Lastly, what are your requirements on pcb space and price? What do you require for analog accuracy? This will affect the design. You should set those first and then design the rest of the system around that. If you have lots of regulators and your meeting your requirements, then does it really matter? Nope, your design works.